# convert space separated list of names within a file to json formatted json file

Tags: python, json, jq, convertto-json

I have a space separated list of names generated by a program, I need to convert this list to json. I can not change the program generating the file output. I need to convert the output in file names.txt to json.

example: file output is called names.txt. context is below.

```
name1 name2 name3
```

The json expectation is

```json
{
    "names": [
        "name1",
        "name2",
        "name3"
    ]
}
```

I have [boto3](/questions/tagged/boto3) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) at my disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) solution could be simplefied by passing the 'string' as argument, then using `split()` to create an array like so:

```
jq -n --arg d "$(cat input)" '{ "names": $d | split(" ") }'
```

Local example:

```
$ cat input
name1 name2 name3
$
$ jq -n --arg d "$(cat input)" '{ "names": $d | split(" ") }'
{
  "names": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ]
}
$
$
```

Comment: Is `-s` necessary ?

Comment: Nope, not sure why I've included that. Copy/paste error I guess. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and use dictionary comprehension

```
with open('names.txt') as file:
    d = {'names': name.split(' ') for name in file}
    
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the first line, split on whitespace, the create the desired dictionary

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    names = f.readline().spilt()
    data = {'names': names}
```

To later get this into valid json you can use `dump` or `dumps` depending what you need to pass this to

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"names": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]}'
```